# How to search for certain elements in a chronological order in text to create simplified dataframe

Tags: r, string, function, loops, apply

**Intro to data**

I have a text file document or csv, which contains the coding from a website, where I could not export the data to an excel sheet. That means that the data itself is bunch of code, where elements are differentiated by certain bits of text.

*Understanding the data*

Fx. Each varaible starts with `<a:FN>`. each element in the varaible, x, has a code that starts with `<a:DT>...` 
and y has a code that starte with `<a:KY>...` where the value for this element starts with `<a:VL>`.
The coding for each variable, as well as the underlying code related to this variable, starts with `<a:PLI>`.

**Data structure**

```
So the structure of the file is as following: 


   `<a:PLI>`
      <a:DT>...
       `<a:FN>...` 
          `<a:KY>...`
           <a:VL>...
    `<a:PLI>`
      <a:DT>...
       `<a:FN>...` 
           `<a:KY>...`
            <a:VL>...
```

When imported to R, the dataframe only has 1 column and a total of approx. 35.000 rows. Each bit of code has its own row.

**What I wish to do & Expected result**

What I want to do, is transform this complicated text file into a new dataframe, containing all the elements that I am interested in.

For example for each group/variable `(a<:FN)` I want to find X `(<a:DT>)`, where I then want to find Y `(<a:KY>org-key</a:KY>)` and Z `(<a:VL)` to the org-key. 
I want to do this for all X's in all groups/varaibles, resulting in an output, where each X is grouped with its respecting Y and Z value.

I am not sure how to solve my question. I have thought that a for-loop might be the way, or using something from the apply-family like sapply. Frankly I am unsure where to even start, which is why I am reaching out.

What I have envisioned to do, is set up a function that describes what it is I want to do:

```
bespoke <- function (x) {

find x in df      ## X could be one of the varaibles I am looking for
find y after x    ## Find y for x in df
find z after x    ## find z for x in df
return all elements to a df  ## I wnat to repeat this function for all variables in df. 
}

df2 <- adply(keys, bespoke)
```

I am not used to working with functions, so I don't really know how to even start, also because I have several underlying critieria for my function that I want to follow.

I hope that someone can help me move forward.

**Piece of data:**

```
    <a:PLI>
       <a:DT>False</a:DT>
       <a:DTR>False</a:DTR>
       <a:Desc>text text text</a:Desc>
       <a:FN>Type</a:FN>
       <a:PSPS>
          <a:PSP>
             <a:KY>org-group</a:KY>
             <a:VL>40100</a:VL>
          </a:PSP>
          <a:PSP>
             <a:KY>org-key</a:KY>
             <a:VL>60205</a:VL>
          </a:PSP>
          <a:PSP>
             <a:KY>org-systemkey</a:KY>
             <a:VL>1005</a:VL>
          </a:PSP>
          <a:PSP>
             <a:KY>org-report-type</a:KY>
             <a:VL>text text text</a:VL>
          </a:PSP>
       </a:PSPS>
       <a:TI>80200</a:TI>
    </a:PLI>
    <a:PLI>
       <a:DT>Room</a:DT>
       <a:DTR>Room</a:DTR>
       <a:Desc/>
       <a:FN>StartRoom</a:FN>
       <a:PSPS>
          <a:PSP>
             <a:KY>org-group</a:KY>
             <a:VL>13020</a:VL>
          </a:PSP>
          <a:PSP>
             <a:KY>org-key</a:KY>
             <a:VL>13130</a:VL>
          </a:PSP>
       </a:PSPS>
       <a:TI>12500</a:TI>
    </a:PLI>
    <a:PLI>
       <a:DT>Other room</a:DT>
       <a:DTR>Other room</a:DTR>
       <a:Desc/>
       <a:FN>StartRoom</a:FN>
       <a:PSPS>
          <a:PSP>
             <a:KY>org-group</a:KY>
             <a:VL>11160</a:VL>
          </a:PSP>
          <a:PSP>
             <a:KY>org-key</a:KY>
             <a:VL>15152</a:VL>
          </a:PSP>
       </a:PSPS>
       <a:TI>15552</a:TI>
    </a:PLI>
```

Comment: I believe that I need to use stringr in the function to look for the pieces of code that I want to compile... something like str_starts(<a:FN>)

Comment: It would be easier to help if you could share a small reproducible example along with expected output.

Comment: I have added a bit of the data that I am looking at. As for expected output, a dataframe of the variables that I want an overview of: <a:DT>, <a: FN>, <a: KY>org-group..., <a:VL> value to org-group, <a:KY>org-key... and <a:VL> value to org-key.

Comment: I think my answer should work now.

Answer (score 1):

(Sorry for the previous wrong answer, I missed an important part of your question)

Here is how I would do that:

1. Wrap the text in a pair of tags so it is valid xml (i.e., add a root node)
2. Remove all the 'a:' (namespace prefixes)

Then, in R:

```
library(xml2)
foo <- read_xml("tmp.xml")

# convert to a nodeset
allplis <- xml_find_all(foo, "//PLI")

xtractpli <- function(x) {
  dt <- xml_text(xml_find_first(x, "DT"))
  fn <- xml_text(xml_find_first(x, "FN"))
  orgkey <- xml_find_first(x, "PSPS/PSP[KY='org-key']")
  orgkey <- xml_text(xml_find_first(orgkey, "VL"))
  return(c(fn, dt, orgkey))
}

t(sapply(allplis, xtractpli))
```

Result:

```
     [,1]        [,2]         [,3]   
[1,] "Type"      "False"      "60205"
[2,] "StartRoom" "Room"       "13130"
[3,] "StartRoom" "Other room" "15152"
```

Is this what you wanted?

Comment: Yes - that was what I was going for! Thank you. 
I understand what you have done, I now "only" have trouble reading my data. What do you mean by "wrap the text in pairs"?

Comment: Put a '<whatever>' at the beginning of your file, and '</whatever>' a the end of your file and you are good to go.

Answer (score 1):

You are actually dealing with a type of XML, where the `a` before the `:` is referred to as its "namespace". Assuming the rest of the data is similar to the sample you've provided, you can extract the data using something like the following code, where `s` is the data you provided (you will need to replace `s` with your file name):

```r
library(rvest)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

vars <- c("dt", "dtr", "desc", "fn", "ti", "ky", "vl")

read_html(s) %>% 
    html_nodes("pli") %>% 
    unclass() %>% 
    map_df(~ map2(list(.), vars, ~ html_text(html_nodes(.x, .y))) %>% 
               set_names(vars) %>% 
               as_tibble,
           .id = "pli"
           )
```

I use `read_html` instead of `read_xml` because it parses the XML pretty well in this case, and I don't feel like fooling around with the namespaces. I can't guarantee that this will always work. There appears to be only one namespace in your sample data, so maybe you'll be okay.

After that I pull out three `pli` nodes using `html_nodes`, and then convert the XML nodeset into a list with `unclass`. In `map_df` I iterate over each of three list elements (the three `pli` nodes), and apply `map2`, where I pull out all the relevant nodes using the values in `vars` and store the output in a tibble. The results should look like this:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 8
  pli   dt         dtr        desc           fn        ti    ky              vl            
  <chr> <chr>      <chr>      <chr>          <chr>     <chr> <chr>           <chr>         
1 1     False      False      text text text Type      80200 org-group       40100         
2 1     False      False      text text text Type      80200 org-key         60205         
3 1     False      False      text text text Type      80200 org-systemkey   1005          
4 1     False      False      text text text Type      80200 org-report-type text text text
5 2     Room       Room       ""             StartRoom 12500 org-group       13020         
6 2     Room       Room       ""             StartRoom 12500 org-key         13130         
7 3     Other room Other room ""             StartRoom 15552 org-group       11160         
8 3     Other room Other room ""             StartRoom 15552 org-key         15152
```

Comment: Thank you! 
Do you happen to know why, when reading in may data, everything is empty, meaning that my end result tibble: 0x0? My data was shared via. Notepad and I moved it to excel - has sth. maybe gone wrong here?

Comment: @BloopFloopy hard to say without seeing your actual data. It probably has something to do with the XML, e.g. namespace etc.